# How to use SoundCloud API to filter by genres

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the API of SoundCloud without success, most examples and tutorials on the web are not working. 
For the purpose I used this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TuqjGxosrc). I wish to create on my website a filter by genres.
So first I created an HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src="js/soundcloud.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="genre">punk</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="genre">rap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="genre">rock</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and than a JavaScript (soundcloud.js):

```
function playSomeSound(genre){
SC.get('/tracks',{
    genres:genre,
    bpm:{
      from:100
    }
  }, function(tracks){
    var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*49);
    SC.oEmbed(tracks[random]).uri,{auto_play:true}, document.getElementById('target')
  });
}

window.onload=function(){
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'my_app_id'
  });

  var menuLinks=document.getElementsByClassName('genre');
  for (var i=0; i<menuLinks.lenght;i++){
    var menuLink=menuLinks[i];
    menuLink.onclick=function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      playSomeSound(menuLink.innerHTML);
    }
  }

};
```

When I navigate to my website everything is fine, I get no errors from console, however if I click on a genre, it does nothing.
Why it doesn't retrieve songs from SoundCloud?
SoundCloud has changed different things for API use, is there another method?

Comment: it does nothing like if you put some console.log (or alerts) at then menuLink.onclick function it actually does nothing ?

Comment: @JanxfromVenezuela Hi, onClick of one of those listed genre, no errors from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<menuLinks.lenght;i++){ //it should be .length and not lenght
    var menuLink=menuLinks[i];
    menuLink.onclick=function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      playSomeSound(menuLink.innerHTML);
    }
  }
```

Also, you misplaced a parenthesis on SC.embed. Here's a working solution: http://jsbin.com/pugegesepu/1/edit